# How to include all levels in a ggplot legend when using d_plyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

**goal:** a legend which contains two levels of a factor, even if both levels are not represented on the figure

minimum reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

mre <- data.frame(plotfactor = factor(rep(c("response1", "response2"), c(2, 
    2))), linefactor = factor(rep(c("line1", "line2"), 2)), x1 = runif(n = 4), 
    x2 = runif(n = 4), y1 = runif(n = 4), y2 = runif(n = 4), ltype = c("foo", 
        "foo", "foo", "bar"))

## this looks great!
ggplot(mre, aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2, colour = linefactor, 
linetype =  ltype)) + geom_segment() + facet_wrap(~plotfactor)
```

[image: pretty example]

### the problem

**However**, If I use a `plyr` function to print each plot to a separate page of a 
pdf, the legend for ltype only contains the single factor level that appears in the subset of the dataframe that `d_ply` passes to ggplot -- i.e., it only says "foo".  I want it to say both "foo" and "bar", even if the level "bar" of the factor ltype does not occur in the graph:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
d_ply(mre, .(plotfactor), function(DF)
    g <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2, colour = linefactor,
    linetype = ltype)) + geom_segment()
    print(g)
    })
dev.off()
```

(forgive me: I have no idea how to produce this effect in a png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `scale_linetype_discrete` to make sure both are on the legend.

```
mre$ltype <- factor(mre$ltype)


plot1 <- ggplot(subset(mre, plotfactor == "response1"), 
    aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2, colour = linefactor, 
    linetype =  ltype)) + 
    geom_segment()  +
    scale_linetype_discrete(drop = FALSE)
    ggsave(plot1, file = "plot1.pdf")

plot2 <- ggplot(subset(mre, plotfactor == "response2"), 
    aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2, colour = linefactor, 
    linetype =  ltype)) + 
    geom_segment()  +
    scale_linetype_discrete(drop = FALSE)
    ggsave(plot2, file = "plot2.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Is using ggsave a better way than print?  And, is there a way to set the drop=FALSE option globally? (mostly just curious)

Comment: Yes, `ggsave` is a much better way. The format is the file extension. e.g. change to `png` for a web page, `.tiff` for a presentation. Can also specify size and units. See `?ggsave` for more opts.

Comment: Can't set `drop = FALSE` globally unless you wrap around another custom geom. Easiest would be to write a small custom function and have this as the default inside. You can even pass a file name for `ggsave` in that function.