# Extracting and plotting facet_wrap elements along with same legend key with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot each element of `facet_wrap` separately along with the same legend key.  I know this can be achieved with subset on **class**  but in that case the legend key can be different for different levels of **class** variable.  Here is my MWE.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class)
```

[image]

Actually this is required for administrative plots to plot different states with the same legend key but at different latitude and longitude.

### Edited

```
library(XML)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(maps)

unemp <-
  readHTMLTable('http://www.bls.gov/web/laus/laumstrk.htm',
                colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'numeric'))[[2]]

names(unemp) <- c('rank', 'region', 'rate')
unemp$region <- tolower(unemp$region)

us_state_map <- map_data('state')
map_data <- merge(unemp, us_state_map, by = 'region')

map_data <- arrange(map_data, order)
map_data$subregion <- rep(c("A", "B"), c(8000, 7537))

states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)

p1 <- ggplot(data = map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p1 <- p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(rate, 5)))
p1 <- p1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p1 <- p1 + coord_map()
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

```
p1 + facet_wrap(~subregion, nrow=1)
```

[image]

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = subset(map_data, subregion=="A"), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p2 <- p2 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(rate, 5)))
p2 <- p2 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p2 <- p2 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p2 <- p2 + coord_map()
p2 <- p2 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p2 <- p2 + theme_bw()
p2
```

[image]

```
p3 <- ggplot(data = subset(map_data, subregion=="B"), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p3 <- p3 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(rate, 5)))
p3 <- p3 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p3 <- p3 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p3 <- p3 + coord_map()
p3 <- p3 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p3 <- p3 + theme_bw()
p3
```

[image]

Please see last three plots have different scales and legend keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include all levels in a ggplot legend when using d\_plyr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157385/how-to-include-all-levels-in-a-ggplot-legend-when-using-d-plyr)

Comment: This is not a duplicate @EDi. Please see my edits with MWE. Actually I was avoiding to have lot of code and graphs in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset and use `scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to avoid dropping the unused factor levels.

Here's an example:

```
require(ggplot2)
mtcars$f_gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, col = f_gear)) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(mtcars[1:2, ], aes(x = disp, y = hp, col = f_gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

**Update**

You could specify the fill before plotting:

```
map_data$cuts <- cut_number(map_data$rate, 5)
p2 <- ggplot(data = subset(map_data, subregion=="A"), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p2 <- p2 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cuts))
p2 <- p2 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p2 <- p2 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p2 <- p2 + coord_map()
p2 <- p2 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p2 <- p2 + theme_bw()
p2

p3 <- ggplot(data = subset(map_data, subregion=="B"), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p3 <- p3 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cuts))
p3 <- p3 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p3 <- p3 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p3 <- p3 + coord_map()
p3 <- p3 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p3 <- p3 + theme_bw()
p3
```

Comment: Thanks @EDi for your answer. Please see my edits for the problem mentioned earlier.